# How to jump X second with axWindowsMediaPlayer in C#

Tags: c#, video, windows-media-player, winapi, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am using axWindowsMediaPlayer, and I have a video loaded, but I want to jump X seconds.  So, for example, if the current time is 1 minute into the video, I want to jump to 1 minute 10 seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I found my solution.  I was actually running it correctly, but I was not accounting for the time it takes to load the video.

Specifically, the needed code is like

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition += 10;
```

However I wrote a function to check to see if the video had finished loading and attached a timer to it

```
private bool isPlaying()
{
   return axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPPlayState.wmppsReady || axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying;
}
```

Then called my skip function when I got a true.